# Series converge or diverge

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ a_n> 0$ for all $ n\in N$. Prove that 
$\displaystyle  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$  and    $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {a_n   }  { 1+a_n  }$
both converge or both diverge.

I need a Hint, please!.

Comment: what have you tried? If the first series converges what can you say about the latter series? what tests can you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: $\dfrac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \le a_n$

Hint 2: If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{1 + a_n}$ converges then $\dfrac{a_n}{1 + a_n} \to 0$ which implies in turn that $a_n \to 0$.  There is then an index $N$ with the property that $n \ge N$ implies $a_n \le 1$, and thus $n \ge N$ implies $a_n \le \dfrac{2a_n}{1 + a_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $b_n=\dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}$. Then, conversely $a_n=\dfrac{b_n}{1-b_n}$. This shows  $a_n\to 0\iff b_n\to 0$. Hence

- $\sum_n a_n$ diverges trivially if and only if $\sum_n b_n$ diverges trivially.
- If $a_n\to 0$ ($\iff b_n\to 0$), $\;a_n\sim_\infty b_n$. Thus $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ both diverge or both converge.